# I am looking for a simple way to translate words highlighted in the browser

Tags: browser, languages

This is my use case: I'm trying to improve my Spanish so I've started reading Spanish-language newspapers in the browser on my phone. What I'd like to do is this: when I need a word or phrase translated to English, highlight the text, hit the settings button, and have a translate option show up. Or something comparably simple.

Currently the only options that show up under settings when a word is highlighted are: Share, Find, Web Search

I have Google Translate installed and I realize that I could copy the highlighted text and then paste it into that app, but I'd prefer something that didn't require jumping between apps.

Comment: Have you checked with the "Share option"? Some nice gimmicks hidden behind it. And some might be added (or rather add themselves). You could check the playstore for some dictionary apps; I don't know which plug themselfs into the Share-menu, but a good choice to start with would be e.g. [ColorDict Dictionary Wikipedia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.colordict). If it works (I use it together with Moon+ Reader on my tab), it should be as simple as mark a word, menu, share, ColorDict -- et voila :)

Comment: @Izzy You know what? That's exactly what I was looking for. I even looked for the share option at one point and, despite listing it in my question above, completely spaced over it. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll be happy to select it.

Comment: Glad I found an exact match for you! Enjoy learning :) By the way: That's how I try improving my English: Reading English books with Moon+ Reader. If I get stuck at some word unknown to me, I mark it and look it up with ColorDict. Sounds familiar? :D Btw: I guess *Google Translate* (you mentioned using it) also integrates with the search menu -- at least that would make much sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe the options displayed with a word highlighted including "Share". Behind this item hides an entire menu, the so-called "Share menu", where many apps plug themselves in as receivers for compatible content. A highlighted word might serve as such content for several things -- e.g. a web search (so *Google Search* could pick it), send by mail/SMS, or -- the interesting part here -- some dictionary/translator app. While I'd suspect *Google Search* could cover that as well, I want to give you another interesting idea:

[ColorDict Dictionary Wikipedia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.colordict) is an app that can be used for online and offline "word lookup" in dictionaries, be it translation, synonyms, or definitions. The app supports a bunch of dictionaries for offline use, as well as several online dictionaries and, the name suggests it, Wikipedia. If it integrates with the "Share menu" (which I guess it does), this would make the perfect candidate for you:

[image: ColorDict] [image: ColorDict]
<sup>ColorDict (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Thanks again. Google Translate is available through the share option and exactly what I was looking for. Very helpful for language learning, especially with its text-to-speech feature.